# Textbook (or similar) for finite multivalued logic

Tags: logic, reference-request, fuzzy-logic, multivalued-logic

There are a few sources mentioned on some questions on this site regarding multivalued logics, but usually they are to original papers, or to texts on fuzzy logic.  I have access to some fuzzy logic texts, but even these aren't really "textbooks" in the usual sense, with exercises, and obviously they focus on the infinite-valued cases.  Any ideas for ones with exposition aimed at a student (not grad/research student, but one who has had both formal logic and a decent abstract algebra course) and including some basic exercises?

As an example of something I'd like: The appendix to [this paper](http://irafm.osu.cz/research_report/33_rep33.pdf) has statements about "normal forms for $k$-valued logical functions" and "Rosser-Turquette", but even [this Math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/468855/what-are-the-rosser-turquette-axioms-of-lukasiewicz-3-valued-propositional-logic) really assumes quite a bit of background and no explicit examples (unsurprising given the audience, of course).  At [this related MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/139823/what-are-the-rosser-turquette-axioms-of-lukasiewicz-3-valued-propositional-logic/139997#139997) a text is mentioned, but I have a feeling this might not be appropriate and don't want to waste time trying for an ILL, since as very much a non-specialist who just happens to feel fuzzy about fuzzy logic, it's hard to assess suitability from abstracts.

Comment: And yes, I did create a new tag: my understanding is that fuzzy is not identical at all to multivalued - I want three-valued information primarily.

Comment: Merrie Bergmann, [An Introduction to Many-Valued and Fuzzy Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=zEwNfoAZEGoC&printsec=frontcover), Oxford UP (2008)

Comment: Bertram Fronhöfer, [Introduction to Many-Valued Logics (2011)](https://web.archive.org/web/20160304103551/http://www.wv.inf.tu-dresden.de/Teaching/SS-2011/mvl/mval.HANDOUT2.pdf)

Comment: Both of these look promising - no time to look deeply now, but can you put those two references in an answer so I can up vote it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see :

- Merrie Bergmann, [An Introduction to Many-Valued and Fuzzy Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=zEwNfoAZEGoC&printsec=frontcover), Oxford UP (2008)
- Bertram Fronhöfer, [Introduction to Many-Valued Logics](https://web.archive.org/web/20160304103551/http://www.wv.inf.tu-dresden.de/Teaching/SS-2011/mvl/mval.HANDOUT2.pdf) (2011)
- Grzegorz Malinowski, [Many-valued Logics](https://books.google.it/books/about/Many_valued_Logics.html?id=UsbeRbxMUyIC&redir_esc=y), Clarendon (1993).

Comment: The first book came in interlibrary loan yesterday, and it is exactly what I'm looking for; thank you!